# How do i have multiple numbers in one js var string

Tags: javascript, discord

Im coding a bot for discord and im making a staff list and im not sure how to have a whole id in a var, here's an example:
`var 223618180445110274 = "staff";`

---

Every time i run it, it says this: `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` and it targets the ID (223618180445110274) and I've tried quotes and such and it still wont work

---

PS. once someone gives me an answer that works i will remove this.

Comment: A variable name can't start with a number

Comment: You just can't start a variable name with number.

Comment: Is there any reason, why  you want number as an identifier?

Comment: @Sreekanth my bot gets the user by id and i need to have the `usersID = "staff"` thing for it to work

Comment: in that case, does grouping all you variables into a object work for you?

Comment: @Sreekanth I'm new to js so im not sure what you mean

Comment: alright, you cant really declare variables dynamically. However, you could create new key value pairs based on some input, in your case the user id. you could do something like var Ids = { }; ids["223618180445110274"] = "staff"; and you could access it as  ids["223618180445110274"]

Comment: As per the variable naming, numbers cant be used as variable names. However, you could use them as keys on an object

Comment: @Sreekanth so whould this work? `if(ids["223618180445110274"] = "staff")`

Comment: yes it should. minor change it should be == not =

Comment: I got a error `ReferenceError: ids is not defined`

Comment: you need to declare and populate the ids object first to access them. If you haven't declared / populated them , you would run into these issues.

Comment: @Sreekanth this is the code i got, i probably made a huge mistake knowing me: [ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/d6mawx)

Comment: you should use Ids instead of ids. I think, it would be a good starter for you to get a feel of JS from the link mentioned as a closure for this question. it is very well explained on naming conventions and other details.

Comment: @Sreekanth thank you so much!, i got it to work now [Screenshot of output](http://prntscr.com/d6mc3d)

Comment: glad your problem is resolved